# Download a file from web Server

Tags: php, jquery, email, download

I have a web running on a server and I manage several files. I want users can download a certain files generated but I can't force to download this files, and I tried several ways to do it. Mails with files attached (3 different ways) or by forcing the file download through the web browser... Nothing happens.

I have this configuration in `JS` (`jQuery`) to `PHP` script:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./download_file.php",
                data: {download_file: jsonFilename}, 
                cache: false,

                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

In `PHP` force download:

```
$file = json_decode($_POST['download_file']);

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file);
readfile("./uploads/subtitles/" . $file);
```

In `PHP` PHPMailer:

```
require_once('./PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');

$file = json_decode($_POST['download_file']);
$bodytext = 'Here is your file!';

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'admin@mail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Web Administrator';
$email->Subject   = 'Download';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'user@mail.co' );

$file_to_attach = './path/' . $file;

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , $file );

return $email->Send();
```

Also I tried this other way in `PHP`:

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto,$from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}

$file = json_decode($_POST['download_file']);
$bodytext = 'Here is your file';
//start editing and inputting attachment details here
$my_file = $file;
$my_path = "./path/";
$my_name = "Web Administrator";
$my_mail = "admin@mail.com";
$my_replyto = "admin@mail.com";
$my_subject = "whatever";
$my_message = $bodytext;
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "user@mail.co", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
```

I only want user gets his file, but nothing seems to work by the moment.

My web is running on a CentOS server and web-server `lighthttpd`.

Thank you

Comment: just use `location.href='./download_file.php?downloadfile=....'` using `$_GET` or if you really need do it by POST create a hidden form `action="download_file.php"` and submit it to `<iframe>`